# In Kettle, how to acquire table output step's db connection when this step is called? Instead of get all db connection at first

Tags: sql, database, kettle

**Problem**:
a simple ktr (a table input step with a hop to a table output step). When start running, kettle get both steps' db connection. But the input step ran for 20 mins (execute sql). After 20 mins, input step started to get data, and passed to Output step, whose db connection had expired.

**Idea**
If the output step can get db connection (Or reconnect) until input step start passing data to it? Instead of get all db connections at first.

Comment: appreciate for any help

Answer (score 0):

You have a step to wait for another step to end, but in this case I don't think that should be the solution, I would try to solve the problem of the Input step spending so much time to retrieve data.
If you can't avoid delays with the input data, you could use two transformations instead of only one, and the Table input step writes to a file so the second transformation when you read the file to copy to the other table doesn't time out.

Comment: thanks for your help. But in my case, it's pretty difficult to use both way. Because I have so many ktrs in many different system. it's a huge work to separate all of them. As same reason, it's also hard for me to solve all ktrs' input-step time delay problem.

Comment: I heard that, maybe kettle DB connection pool can solve this problem. But how to solve? Any suggestions?